# REST Status Code for Not Existing Partly Item

Tags: rest

Trying to put an item referencing towards a non existing object fails in a REST service. The question I can not answer is what would be a good (correct) status code to return (should be something client related and therefore 4XX).

Summary:

```
put(item, {category:categoryXYZ}) //category XYZ is not existing and therefore putting the item should fail.
```

Sow what status code?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `404 Not Found`. Same as for a `GET` when the resource does not exist.

`REST` aim to reuse at best the `HTTP` protocol. Including the verbs and the error code.